# How to configure lighttpd bin-path parameter with flup/python

Tags: python, lighttpd, fastcgi, flup

I am running lighttpd 1.4.26 on Ubuntu 10.04 with Flup 1.0.3 dev version.

When setting up mod_fastcgi, I can successfully get lighttpd to communicate with the fcgi process on a local socket if I spin up the fcgi manually (as www-data) prior to starting lighttpd.

```
sudo su www-data
/webapps/test/test.fcgi
```

then in another shell...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd/start
```

When I try to use the bin-path parameter in the fastcgi.server config to start this process automatically, the process starts, but does not successfully communicate with the process.

I have isolated the messages in the lighttpd\error.log to the following:

Successful (manual start):

```
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (mod_fastcgi.c.3647) handling it in mod_fastcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.468) -- before doc_root
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.469) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.470) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.471) Path         :
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.519) -- after doc_root
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.520) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.521) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.522) Path         : /webapps/test/test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (configfile-glue.c.583) === start of condition block ===
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (configfile-glue.c.541) 1 (cached) result: false
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (configfile-glue.c.583) === start of condition block ===
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (configfile-glue.c.541) 2 (cached) result: false
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.539) -- logical -> physical
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.540) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.541) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.542) Path         : /webapps/test/test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (mod_fastcgi.c.3071) got proc: pid: 0 socket: unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock load: 1
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (connections.c.1773) state at exit: 7 handle-req
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (mod_fastcgi.c.1492) released proc: pid: 0 socket: unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock load: 0
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (connections.c.1367) state at start 7 handle-req
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (connections.c.1431) state for fd 7 handle-req
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (connections.c.1511) state for fd 7 resp-start
2012-01-03 11:56:52: (response.c.128) Response-Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Content-Type: text/plain^M
Content-Length: 13^M
Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2012 19:56:52 GMT^M
Server: lighttpd/1.4.26^M
```

Unsuccessful:

```
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (mod_fastcgi.c.3647) handling it in mod_fastcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.468) -- before doc_root
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.469) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.470) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.471) Path         :
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.519) -- after doc_root
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.520) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.521) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.522) Path         : /webapps/test/test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (configfile-glue.c.583) === start of condition block ===
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (configfile-glue.c.541) 1 (cached) result: false
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (configfile-glue.c.583) === start of condition block ===
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (configfile-glue.c.541) 2 (cached) result: false
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.539) -- logical -> physical
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.540) Doc-Root     : /webapps/test
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.541) Rel-Path     : /test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (response.c.542) Path         : /webapps/test/test.fcgi
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (mod_fastcgi.c.3071) got proc: pid: 23117 socket: unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock-0 load: 1
2012-01-03 11:53:17: (connections.c.1773) state at exit: 7 handle-req
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1367) state at start 8 error
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1746) shutdown for fd 8
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1598) state for fd 8 close
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1621) connection closed for fd 8
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1587) state for fd 8 connect
2012-01-03 11:53:27: (connections.c.1773) state at exit: 8 connect
```

My fastcgi config:

```
server.modules   += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

## Start an FastCGI server
fastcgi.debug = 1

fastcgi.server    = ( ".fcgi" =>
                      ( "localhost" =>
                        (
                        "socket" => "/tmp/fcgi.sock",
                        #"bin-path" => "/webapps/test/test.fcgi",
                        "max-procs" => 1,
                        "check-local" => "disable"
                                        )
                                      )
                                )
```

The only change I am making is to uncomment the bin-path line to reference the fcgi file directly.

The contents of the fcgi file are just a simple hello world:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

def myapp(environ, start_response):
    print 'got request: %s' % environ
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World!\n']

WSGIServer(myapp, bindAddress = '/tmp/fcgi.sock').run()
```

I am new to lighttpd, so perhaps I am missing something simple.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in my installation of lighttpd and Django with flup.
Resolved it by setting up flup for socket file `xxx.sock-0` instead of `xxx.sock` as before.
It may work for you too.

It looks a bit hacky. I am not a Linux guru, may be somebody else will respond with a solution.